# Continuous function nowhere Differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential

Let $D(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be:
$$ D(x)=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}\sin((k+1)!x)$$
Prove that $D(x)$ is nowhere differentiable.

What I've done is that I supposed that exist a $x\in \mathbb{R}$ where $D(x)$ is differentiables, so:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{D(x+h)-D(x)}{h}=a \Rightarrow$$
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}\sin[(k+1)!(x+h)]-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}\sin((k+1)!x)}{h}=$$
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}[\sin[(k+1)!(x+h)]-\sin((k+1)!x)]}{h}=$$
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{ 2\sin(\frac{(k+1)!(x+h)-(k+1)!x}{2})\cos(\frac{(k+1)!(x+h)+(k+1)!x}{2})}{h}=$$
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{ 2\sin(\frac{(k+1)!h}{2})\cos(\frac{(k+1)!(2x+h)}{2})}{h}=\frac{0}
{0} $$
Using L'hopital:
$$ \sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(\frac{(k+1)!h}{2})(\frac{(k+1)!}{2})\cos(\frac{(k+1)!(2x+h)}{2})-\sin(\frac{(k+1)!h}{2})(\frac{(k+1)!}{2})\sin(\frac{(k+1)!(2x+h)}{2})}{1} =$$
$$ \sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}\lim_{h\rightarrow0}[(\frac{(k+1)!}{2})\cos(\frac{(k+1)!(2x+h)}{2})] =$$
$$ \sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}(\frac{(k+1)!}{2})\cos((k+1)!(x)) = \sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{k+1}{2}\cos((k+1)!(x)) $$
I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Why is the first limit equal to $0$?

Comment: It was an error, I fixed it.